# Adding IFBLANK turn into 0 on an existing formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, zero

I used this function `=VALUE(RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2) - MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MID(D2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 1) *1)=FALSE,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 0))))` to remove only the right most numbers from a string mixed of letters, special characters, and numbers. Sometimes there are no numbers at the end of the string in which it returns a blank cell. I would like to change the blank cell, however, when I try to select blank cells using "Go to Special" in excel it says "no cells found"

I am wondering if there is a way for the formula to just input zero for blank cells instead

I tried using `=VALUE(IF(ISBLANK(D2), 0, RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2) - MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MID(D2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 1) *1)=FALSE,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 0))))) and =VALUE(IF(D2=" ", 0,  RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2) - MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MID(D2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 1) *1)=FALSE,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))), 0)))))` however it just continues to return blank cells.

Comment: VALUE should return error if you pass no numeric characters instead of blank. Try something like =IFERROR(your_formula, 0)

Comment: With the Value still encompassing it shows an #VALUE! and without it shows a blank still?

Comment: Then wrap your whole formula with IFERROR so instead of #VALUE error it shows 0

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you provide some sample data and the expected output, best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have this option checked in the Excel Options. It might work.

[Show a Zero in cells that have zero value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9kWH.png)